# problem with modelchoicefield show object 1 and object 2 without names?

Tags: django

I have a model structure with code and names I want show a list of choices in modelchoicefield but it shows like this :

```
structure: ---------------------
           structure object (1)
           structure object (2)
```

I don't want to show the name like that.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Structure(models.Model):
    structure_code=models.CharField(max_length=1)
    structure_desig=models.CharField(max_length=350)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.structure_desig

class Service(models.Model):
    structure_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Structure,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    service_desig =models.CharField(max_length=350)

class Immob(models.Model):
    # ...truncated
    service_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Service,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
```

This is the forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from immob.models import Structure
from django import forms

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
{'class':'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=
{'class':'form-control'}))

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', max_length=100)
    structure = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        Structure.objects.all(), 
        to_field_name="structure_desig"
    )
```

What should I do to show the object's name instead of these `structure object(x)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do this by sub-classing the `ModelChoiceField` class and implementing `label_from_instance` like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class MyStructureChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "Structure: #%s" % obj.structure_desig
```

This would let you customise the choice field without needing to change the `__str__` method of `Structure`. Alternatively, just update `Structure.__str__` to format the string how you want it.

Comment: i just want show structure_desig stored in database in dropdownlist that is all and it show object1 it shows object not data stored in database, you can help me more ??

Answer (score 1):

I have suggested two approaches below. Please note that I have not tested either of the below. Based on experience and documentation, I am suggesting so.

(Approach 1) I would have changed the forms.py very slightly like below.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from immob.models import Structure
from django import forms

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['structure'].choices = [(structure_desig_val,structure_desig_val) for structure_desig_val in Structure.objects.all().values_list('structure_desig', flat=True).order_by('structure_desig')]    

    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', max_length=100)
    structure = forms.ChoiceField(label='structure_desig_val_You_should_change_this')
```

Please let me know, if this is working. Otherwise with few times back and forth with more clarifications we can get the code going.

(Approach 2) If you will rather want to be as close as possible to your own code, then I have made very slight adjustment.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from immob.models import Structure
from django import forms

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
{'class':'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=
{'class':'form-control'}))

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', max_length=100)
    structure = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Structure.objects.all(), 
        to_field_name="structure_desig",
        empty_label=None
    )
```

You may try both of them and see which one suits you.

Comment: no doesn't work with me this solution , i just want show structure_desig stored in database in dropdownlist that is all and it show object1 it shows object not data stored in database, you can help me more ??

Comment: Yes it can be done easily. I need to see your views.py. Will you please show the views.py here?

Comment: it is long code ican't put it here because the lmimitation of stackoverflow in comment .. idon't know what can i do ??

Comment: Apologies. I did not mean the whole views.py just the part related to Structure model. Which forms you are using for handling the Structure model and the views? I can write without it but that will break the code. However if you still, can't please let me know so that I will write it with instructions.

Comment: `  def user_registration(request):
    form = UserRegistrationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST': form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid(): username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
        messages.success(request,'saved {}'.format(user.username))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('compte:login'))   
    else:
      form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request,'compte/register.html',{'form':form}) `

Comment: I have edited the forms.py very slightly. See if this is what you wanted. Else we can get the correct code by typing messages a couple of times.

Comment: i got this error when i applied  the seconde modification : Exception Value: 
'UserRegistrationForm' object has no attribute 'get'